# nasm segfault macos mojave 10.14.1

Tags: assembly, printf, nasm, macos-mojave

I recently updated my OS, I am now under Mojave 10.14.1. I updated my Xcode as well which successfully removed my warning at linking time.
But I still can't figure out why a simple printf program with NASM x86_64 now always segfault at the end of its execution...
Here is my code :

```
  section .data
    str db "Hello World", 10

section .text
    global start
    global _main
    extern _printf

start:
    call _main
    ret

_main:
    push    rbp
    sub rsp, rbp
    sub rsp, 16
    lea rdi, [rel str]
    call    _printf
    xor rax, rax
    leave
    ret
```

The Hello World message is always print to the stdout as expected but it gives me a segfault afterward...
Here is my compilations lines

```
nasm -fmacho64 hello.s -o hello.o
ld hello.o -macosx_version_min 10.12 -lSystem
```

With lldb, I can't really understand the problem but I got this :

```
thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)
    frame #0: 0x0000000000001fdc a.out`main + 47
a.out`main:
->  0x1fdc <+47>: leave
    0x1fdd <+48>: retq

a.out`printf:
    0x1fde <+0>:  jmpq   *0x2c(%rip)               ; (void *)0x00007fff750f48ec: printf
    0x1fe4:       leaq   0x1d(%rip), %r11          ; (void *)0x0000000000087e80: initialPoolContent + 624
Target 1: (a.out) stopped.
```

if anyone knows how to solve this, it would be a great help ! 
Thank you !

Comment: My bad, indeed ! thank you very much ! I still need to figure out how does the stack exactly works ... atleast the segfault is now solved !

Comment: I  made a typo in my original. It should have been: `sub rsp, rbp` should be `mov rbp, rsp` . `sub rsp, 16` won't hurt, but it isn't needed since you don't have any local variables.